# Use Ibutton to wake MCU and fire an interrupt

Tags: arduino, avr, gpio-external-interrupt

I'm working on  a battery powered device which takes tree inputs, two buttons and one ibutton. Each input must be able to wake the MCU(Atmega1284p with arduino bootloader) from sleep. With the two buttons i have used an interrupt and it goes well. Then the MCU wakes I can tell the difference of which button was pressed by setting a variable in the ISR function. 
However now I want to be able to wake the MCU by either the two buttons or the ibutton. Unfortunately the ibutton only creates a very short pull down on the signal line for approximate 40us.[image: Oscilloscope view of the signal line when an ibutton just become present.] This means that the MCU will wake but the interrupt will not be fired. From page 30 in the datasheet of the MCU(http://www.atmel.com/images/doc8059.pdf) I can see that i need to keep my signal down for 65ms+14ck. This behavior is described on page 65 at the bottom of section 11.1.

My initial solution was to check if any of the other interrupts was fired, if not then assume the mcu was woken up by the ibutton. The drawback is that if the sleep time ended i would not be able to tell the difference.

My second solution was to use an ibutton port with tactile feedback. Then use the tactile feedback to wake the MCU. But this will increase the hardware cost.

The question is now, is there a smarter way to do this?

**EDIT:** 
It has turned out that I only see these pull downs when i'm not hitting it perfectly clean hence short the signal line to gnd. This means that i'm anyway not able to relie on this event happening. Back to rethink how to wake the MCU with an ibutton.

Comment: Are you simply sleeping the AVR or powering it down? From my reading of the data sheet the 65ms+14ck is if the chip was powered down and you wake it by generating a reset. According to what page 65 references the minimum interrupt pulse is 40ns. Since it is asynchronous it will be latched until the CPU wakes up and deal with it.

Comment: Also AFAIR iButtons are slave devices so really you can't use it to wake anything up.

Comment: It's been a while since I've used iButtons but what you've added in your edit make sense - the 1-wire bus can have multiple devices attached so if it worked that way it'd interfere with other devices. I think your only option might be to periodically wake up and do the presence detect sequence.

Comment: Peter, I did the same in a ATtiny45 based onewire tester I had developed. It wakes up when the onewire cable is attached. Unfortunately, it wasn't reliable in all situations so I had to add a reset button. (-_-)

Comment: @TonyK: Hm... I use the power down sleep mode, that why I thought that. But I see your point on the bottom of page 327, it says typical 50 ns. I will try investigating this...

Comment: @Janka why would you use a reset button?

Comment: When ever i'm putting the ibutton on the probe, i have to be really precise not to short the GND and Signal line. Even when trying hard I fail 9 out of 10 times. However it generates a small signal change on the signal line. The is plausible to use but not so reliable...

Comment: It's the simplest way to wake up from deep sleep.

Comment: @Janka so you added an external button and wired to reset, or did you use a probe with tactile feedback? 
I belive the user experiance will be confusing if they have to push a button before they can use the ibutton...

Comment: To clarify, do you have a mechanism for the user to insert the iButton? If so maybe you can devise a jumper pad or something which will be bridged when the iButton is inserted, and generating an interrupt.

Comment: Simple button, nothing embedded into the iButton socket. Sorry.

Comment: @TonyK Unfortunately not it is just to DS9092 probe panel mounted. But from this I think i will just buy the one with tactile feedback for interrupt even trough it cost more than twice the normal one...

Comment: Update: I found out that the probe with tactile feedback was litterly just a spring... I through it was conntected to a switch...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I ended up using was utilizing the Watch Dog Timer. Using the Arduino OneWire Library the search of a present button takes approximate less than 2 ms. Now I use the WDT to wake up my device every 250 ms to search for the button. This is not as efficient as if the MCU was woken up only then a button is present. However it is still relatively low power.

I found great information regarding the waking the device using the WDT here: http://www.gammon.com.au/forum/?id=11497